# How to read and mab sub array from category res.json useSWR x mongodb x nexjt (node js)

Tags: node.js, arrays, json, mongodb, next.js

anybody here can help me ????
how to read and map array inside json ????????

Hook (useSWR / useCategories) :

```
import useSWR from "swr"
const fetcher = (...args) => fetch(...args).then(res => res.json())
function useCategories () {
    
  const { data, error } = useSWR(`/api/categories`, fetcher)
  const sub = data.sub[0]
  
    return {
      categories: data,
      sub: sub,
      categoriesLoading: !error && !data,
      categoriesError: error
    }
  }

  export {useCategories}
```

page :

```
const {categories, sub, categoriesLoading } = useCategories()
```

component / use ?? :

```
{!categories ? 'Loading' : (<>
        {categories.map(category => (
            <div key={category.slug}>
                name : {category.name}
                sub:{!sub ? '': (<>{sub.map(sub => (<><p key={sub._id}>{sub.name}</p></>))}</>)} 

            </div>
        ))}
        </>)}
```

thanks before senpaiiiii >.<

Answer (score 2):

remove

> const sub = data.sub[0]

then :

```
import {useCategories} from '../useCategories'

export default function pages() {

const {categories, categoriesLoading } = useCategories()

return(<>
{!categories ? 'loading categories..' : (<>
        {categories.map(category => (
            <div key={category.slug}>
                name : {category.name}
                sub: {!category.subs ? 'no sub' : 
               (<>{category.subs.map(sub => (
                <div key={sub._id}>
                sub list : {sub.name}
                </div>
                ))}</>)}

            </div>
        ))}
        </>)}
</>)

}
```